# Is there a way to self get into input text if item exist in dropdown list?

Tags: javascript, html, blazor

I'm working in Blazor .NET 5 on a system to book tickets, when you enter for the first time to make the reservation in the select dropdown list you will see "Choose your name" and "New Passenger". For example: [image: first time reservation]

In the case that there is one or more passengers in the list, (in this case "Testc Testc" is our test passenger) I need to get loaded per default or self binded this data to the inputs text **without having to click** when user re-entering to the order ticket system and want to add more tickets to the same order. [image: case to do example]

I try doing a function to save the iterated list (if passengers.Count() > 0) and pass to input on @bind-value="myfunction()" but it's not possible that way. Maybe i need to use javascript?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: You should have a property for the selected passenger and bind to it.  If there is one or more passengers in the list, set the property and the UI should be updated accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a rather detailed answer and I've made some big guesses.  [I've sat on a plane all morning and got bored].

There are several design considerations, principally:

1. You are switching in and out of edit mode and need to consider how to track data state.
2. You are probably interfacing with an async DB context or a Web API.

I've created an interface to decribe the data pipeline functionality we need to interact with the passenger data store.  It's all async.

```cs
public interface IDataBroker
{
    public ValueTask<IQueryable<Passenger>> GetPassengersAsync();
    public ValueTask<Passenger?> GetItemAsync(Guid uid);
    public ValueTask<bool> AddItemAsync(Passenger record);
    public ValueTask<bool> UpdateItemAsync(Passenger record);
    public ValueTask<bool> DeleteItemAsync(Passenger record);
}
```

I've defined the Passenger record like this:

```cs
public sealed record Passenger
{
    public Guid Uid { get; init; } = Guid.Empty;
    public string FirstName { get; set; } = "Not Set";
    public string LastName { get; set; } = "Not Set";
}
```

And an edit context for this record:

```cs
public sealed class PassengerEditContext
{
    public Passenger BaseRecord { get; private set; }
    public Guid Uid { get; private set; }
    public string? FirstName { get; set; }
    public string? LastName { get; set; }

    public PassengerEditContext(Passenger passenger)
    {
        this.BaseRecord = passenger;
        this.Load(passenger);
    }

    public void Load(Passenger? passenger)
    {
        passenger = passenger ?? new();
        this.BaseRecord = passenger;
        this.Uid = passenger.Uid;
        this.FirstName = passenger.FirstName;
        this.LastName = passenger.LastName;
    }

    public Passenger Record => new()
    {
        Uid = this.Uid,
        FirstName = this.FirstName ?? string.Empty,
        LastName = this.LastName ?? string.Empty
    };

    public bool IsDirty => this.BaseRecord != this.Record;
}
```

The view service does all the data management for the component form:

```cs
public sealed class DataPresenterService
{
    private IDataBroker _dataBroker;
    public Task LoadingTask { get; private set; } = Task.CompletedTask;

    public DataPresenterService(IDataBroker dataBroker)
    {
        _dataBroker = dataBroker;
        LoadingTask = this.LoadData();
    }

    public readonly PassengerEditContext Passenger = new(new());

    public IEnumerable<Passenger> Passengers = Enumerable.Empty<Passenger>();

    public async Task LoadData()
        => this.Passengers = await _dataBroker.GetPassengersAsync();

    public async ValueTask GetPassengerAsync(Guid uid)
    {
        var passenger = await _dataBroker.GetItemAsync(uid);
        this.Passenger.Load(passenger);
    }

    public ValueTask ResetPassengerAsync()
    {
        this.Passenger.Load(this.Passenger.BaseRecord);
        return ValueTask.CompletedTask;
    }

    public async ValueTask SavePassengerAsync()
    {

        if (this.Passenger.Uid == Guid.Empty)
        {
            var passenger = this.Passenger.Record with { Uid = Guid.NewGuid() };
            await _dataBroker.AddItemAsync(passenger);
            this.Passenger.Load(passenger);
        }
        else
        {
            var passenger = this.Passenger.Record with { };
            await _dataBroker.UpdateItemAsync(passenger);
            this.Passenger.Load(passenger);
        }
        await LoadData();
    }

    public async ValueTask<bool> DeletePassengerAsync(Passenger passenger)
        => await _dataBroker.DeleteItemAsync(passenger);
}
```

And the Edit Form:

```cs
@page "/"
@inject DataPresenterService Service
<PageTitle>Index</PageTitle>

<h1>Demo</h1>

<div class="m-2 row">
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 mb-2">
        <label class="form-label text-muted small">Passenger</label>
        <select class="form-select" disabled="@_isDirty" value="@this.Service.Passenger.Uid" @onchange=OnChangePassenger>
            @if(this.Service.Passenger.Uid == Guid.Empty)
            {
                <option selected value="@Guid.Empty" > -- Add Passenger -- </option>
            }
            else
            {
                <option value="@Guid.Empty"> -- Add Passenger -- </option>
            }

            @foreach(var passenger in this.Service.Passengers)
            {
                <option value="@passenger.Uid">@passenger.FirstName @passenger.LastName</option>
            }
        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 mb-2">
        <label class="form-label text-muted small">First Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" @bind=this.Service.Passenger.FirstName @bind:event="oninput" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 col-lg-4 mb-2">
        <label class="form-label text-muted small">Last Name</label>
        <input class="form-control" @bind=this.Service.Passenger.LastName @bind:event="oninput" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-12 text-end mb-2">
        <div class="btn-group">
            <button class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" disabled="@_isClean" @onclick=UpdatePassenger>@_saveText</button>
            <button class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" disabled="@_isClean" @onclick=ResetPassenger>Discard</button>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>


@code {
    private bool _isDirty => this.Service.Passenger.IsDirty;
    private bool _isClean => !this.Service.Passenger.IsDirty;
    private bool _isNew => this.Service.Passenger.Uid == Guid.Empty;
    private string _saveText => _isNew ? "Add" : "Update";

    protected async override Task OnInitializedAsync()
        => await this.Service.LoadingTask;

    private async Task OnChangePassenger(ChangeEventArgs e)
    {
        if (BindConverter.TryConvertTo<Guid>(e.Value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, out Guid value))
        {
            await this.Service.GetPassengerAsync(value);
            return;
        }

        await this.Service.GetPassengerAsync(Guid.Empty);
    }

    private async Task UpdatePassenger()
        => await this.Service.SavePassengerAsync();

    private async Task ResetPassenger()
        => await this.Service.ResetPassengerAsync();
}
```

Key Points:

1. Separation of Concerns.  The data is separated from the UI into a View and a data pipeline.
2. The data pipeline is Readonly.  Everything is a `record`.  An edit object, which track state, is used in the edit context.
3. There's no form locking when the data is dirty.  You need to be on Net7.0 for that built in functionality.

### Test Data Provider

Services registered as follows:

```cs
builder.Services.AddScoped<IDataBroker, DataProvider>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<DataPresenterService>();
```

```cs
public sealed class DataProvider : IDataBroker
{
    public async ValueTask<IQueryable<Passenger>> GetPassengersAsync()
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        var list = new List<Passenger>();
        passengers.ForEach(item => list.Add(item with { }));
        return list.AsQueryable();
     }

    public async ValueTask<Passenger?> GetItemAsync(Guid uid)
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        return this.passengers.SingleOrDefault(item => item.Uid == uid);
    }

    public async ValueTask<bool> AddItemAsync(Passenger record)
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        if (this.passengers.Any(item => item.Uid == record.Uid))
            return false;

        this.passengers.Add(record);
        return true;
    }

    public async ValueTask<bool> UpdateItemAsync(Passenger record)
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        if (!this.passengers.Any(item => item.Uid == record.Uid))
            return false;

        var oldRecord = this.passengers.Single(item => item.Uid == record.Uid);
        this.passengers.Remove(oldRecord);
        this.passengers.Add(record);
        return true;
    }

    public async ValueTask<bool> DeleteItemAsync(Passenger record)
    {
        await Task.Yield();
        if (!this.passengers.Any(item => item == record))
            return false;

        var rec = this.passengers.Single(item => item.Uid == record.Uid);
        this.passengers.Remove(record);
        return true;
    }

    private List<Passenger> passengers = new List<Passenger>
    {
        new() { Uid = Guid.NewGuid(), FirstName="John", LastName = "Doe"},
        new() { Uid = Guid.NewGuid(), FirstName="Fred", LastName = "Bloggs"},
        new() { Uid = Guid.NewGuid(), FirstName="Luke", LastName = "Skywalker"},
    };
}
```